Match column and consider blank cell as matched
Please advise the formula if i want to match column a2 to e2 in sheet 1 with any row, column a to e in sheet 2. There are blanks in the columns in sheet 2 and I want to consider these as matched and return column j. Vba solution will be ideal as there are more than 10000 lines but I can try to convert it to VBA if there is a formula to work with. Thanks!
I am only able to come up with the usual formula of
=IF(A2&B2&C2&D2&E2=Sheet2!A:E, Sheet2!("J",""))

But this does not work with the blank nor does it lookup the whole of sheet 2 to find the match.
Updated with sample. If it matches, it should return column J in sheet1 and if not it should be left blank.
Sheet1



NAD
REED
EXX
SNCTR
SECT




BS
BN
FND
AA
444


SS
MY
TH
AA
442


UK
US
EQU
BB
441



Sheet 2



NAD
REED
EXX
SNCTR
SECT




RULES




BS
BN
FND

444




NOT ALLOWED


SS

TH
AA
442




ALLOWED WITH ALLOWANCE


UK
US
EQU
AA
441




NOT APPLICABLE




for the requirement of blank cells matching, can you give an example? will the whole row be blank or will it be a specific column that will be missing?

try this formula in Sheet1 cell F2, edit the ranges as necessary =XLOOKUP(1,((Sheet2!$A$2:$A$11=A2)+(Sheet2!$A$2:$A$11=""))((Sheet2!$B$2:$B$11=B2)+(Sheet2!$B$2:$B$11=""))((Sheet2!$C$2:$C$11=C2)+(Sheet2!$C$2:$C$11=""))((Sheet2!$D$2:$D$11=D2)+(Sheet2!$D$2:$D$11=""))((Sheet2!$E$2:$E$11=E2)+(Sheet2!$E$2:$E$11="")),Sheet2!$J$2:$J$11)

@alph Go with MMULT() or BYROW() function.

Could you share some relevant sample data using this table markdown generator so we have something to work with. Simply copy not more than 21 relevant rows (including the headers) of a table into the website's text box, press Submit, press Copy and paste it into your post (question).

Thanks for the response. I have tried all the formula, and all I am getting is #NAME?. Not sure where it went wrong since i copied the formula. I have updated my question with my sample sheet. Appreciate any advise.

You're getting the #NAME? error because your version of Excel doesn't recognize the functions since they require MS365. The VBA code I previously posted could be improved to accommodate the required behavior but it takes at least 10min to complete 10k rows so it's useless. My currently posted code requires the blank cells to be blank in the source and destination sheets. Again, useless but even worse, at the moment, I don't see a way how to fix it. BTW, why is the first resulting row not a match and which columns are allowed to have blanks and on which sheet?

The 1st and 2nd row are supposed to be matched since blanks are to be overlooked and considered as matched. The 3rd row is a non matched as column D3 differ. Blank cells should only be in sheet2.

I use the same data sample as the previous answer.
You can also use BYROW() to loop through each row in sheet2 to check:
=XLOOKUP(TRUE, BYROW(Sheet2!$A$1:$E$4, LAMBDA(row, AND((A2:E2 = row) + (row = "")))), Sheet2!$I$1:$I$4)


Here is how BYROW() works:

it loops through each row in sheet2:


for each row, it then makes use of Excel formula's superb ability to operate on all cells in a row using a single arithmetic operator to check whether they are either blank or they are the same as A2, B2..etc in sheet1.




Hi thanks for responding. I am getting $CALC! for this formula.

@sipirili what does =AND((A2:E2 = Sheet2!$A$1:$E$1) + (Sheet2!$A$1:$E$1 = "")) return?

i get false for that formula.

@sipirili, then at least that part is working as expected. then how about =BYROW(Sheet2!$A$1:$E$4, LAMBDA(row, AND((A2:E2 = row) + (row = ""))))

This is the (array)formula in G1 and drag down
Empty cells on Sheet2 are handled as identical.
=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet2!$J$1:$J$4,MATCH(CONCATENATE(A1,B1,C1,D1,E1),  
CONCATENATE(IF(Sheet2!$A$1:$A$4="",A1,Sheet2!$A$1:$A$4), 
IF(Sheet2!$B$1:$B$4="",B1,Sheet2!$B$1:$B$4), 
IF(Sheet2!$C$1:$C$4="",C1,Sheet2!$C$1:$C$4), 
IF(Sheet2!$D$1:$D$4="",D1,Sheet2!$D$1:$D$4), 
IF(Sheet2!$E$1:$E$4="",E1,Sheet2!$E$1:$E$4)),0)),"")


With VBA you can assign this formula to the range of required as an array formula

Hi thanks for the response. I managed to get hold of office365 to test this out and it seems to work. How do I assign this as an array formula for VBA. Tried recording the macro to add the formula but it does not seem to work. Also, for sheet 2, there is no definite number of rows so is there a way to pick up the whole column instead of 1 to 4? Thanks for your help!

Using MMULT (as Harun24hr also suggested) to get count blanks or equals per row:

since calculation involving whole columns could be slow, get the max number of rows with data first (this could be further limited by limiting the range if needed):
MAX(IF(NOT(ISBLANK(ae_2_all)), ROW(ae_2_all), 0)...
MMULT(columns in A:E, five 1's for each row) is used to get sum by rows
ae_blank + ae_equal is use get OR(ae_blank, ae_equal) by row
-- is used convert TRUE/FALSE to 1/0

Enter in G1 enter (no need to fill-down):
=LET(
    ae_1, A2:E2, j_2, Sheet2!J1:J10000, ae_2, Sheet2!A1:E10000,
    num_cols, COLUMNS(ae_1),
    ae_blank, MMULT(--(TRIM(ae_2) = ""), SEQUENCE(num_cols, , 1, 0)) =
        num_cols,
    ae_equal, MMULT(--(ae_1 = ae_2), SEQUENCE(num_cols, , 1, 0)) = num_cols,
    IF(ae_blank + ae_equal, IF(TRIM(j_2) = "", "", j_2), "")
)



Hi. Thank you for answering. This does not return any results for me. I tried the one with the last row calculation as the data is huge, but I am getting blank cells even though there are supposed to be results.

@sipirili, thanks for testing. Could you please tell me the ranges you’re using for ae_1 and for other ranges? No need for data. I’ll check and get back to you.

Hihi. It is still blank.

@sipirili, could you please paste the formula with your ranges? I'm not sure why it's all blank. Also, this 'spill' formula needs to be entered only in one cell.

A VBA Lookup: Multiple Columns with a Twist

The rows that appear empty are not i.e. CountBlank would return a number greater than 0 since they had previously contained formulas and were copied using PasteValues. Otherwise, you couldn't use CurrentRegion to reference the complete range.
If you set ARE_BLANKS_A_MATCH to False, only 17 will be returned because it's in the only row where all cells are not blank since a single blank cell disqualifies the row.
Errors are also matched. They have to be of the same type though.
Fell free to use column numbers (integers) instead of column strings or mix it up (a bad idea; best be consistent about it).
You can also return multiple columns.


Main
Sub MatchDataByColumns()

    ' Define constants.
    Const SRC_SHEET_NAME As String = "Sheet2"
    Const SRC_LOOKUP_COLUMNS As String = "A,B,C,D,E" ' or numbers
    Const SRC_RETURN_COLUMNS As String = "J" ' or numbers
    Const DST_SHEET_NAME As String = "Sheet1"
    Const DST_LOOKUP_COLUMNS As String = "A,B,C,D,E" ' or numbers
    Const DST_RETURN_COLUMNS As String = "F" ' or numbers
    Const COLUMNS_DELIMITER As String = ","
    Const CONCAT_DELIMITER As String = "\"
    Const ARE_BLANKS_A_MATCH As Boolean = True
    
    ' Reference the workbook.
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    Dim sJag() As Variant, dJag() As Variant, Cols As Variant, cUB As Long
    
    ' LOOKUP
    
    ' Reference the source range and retrieve the number of rows.
    Dim srg As Range, sRowsCount As Long
    With wb.Sheets(SRC_SHEET_NAME).Range("A1").CurrentRegion
        sRowsCount = .Rows.Count - 1
        If sRowsCount = 0 Then Exit Sub ' no data
        Set srg = .Resize(sRowsCount).Offset(1)
    End With
    
    ' Return the source lookup columns in an array.
    SplitStringToIntegers Cols, cUB, SRC_LOOKUP_COLUMNS, COLUMNS_DELIMITER
    
    ' Populate the source lookup array.
    JagColumnRanges sJag, srg, sRowsCount, Cols, cUB
    Erase Cols
    
    ' Return the concatenated source lookup columns in an array.
    Dim sData() As Variant: ConcatJaggedColumns _
        sData, sJag, sRowsCount, cUB, ARE_BLANKS_A_MATCH, CONCAT_DELIMITER
    Erase sJag
    
    ' Reference the destination range and retrieve the number of rows.
    Dim drg As Range, dRowsCount As Long
    With wb.Sheets(DST_SHEET_NAME).Range("A1").CurrentRegion
        dRowsCount = .Rows.Count - 1
        If dRowsCount = 0 Then Exit Sub ' no data
        Set drg = .Resize(dRowsCount).Offset(1)
    End With
    
    ' Return the destination lookup columns in an array.
    SplitStringToIntegers Cols, cUB, DST_LOOKUP_COLUMNS, COLUMNS_DELIMITER
    
    ' Populate the destination lookup array.
    JagColumnRanges dJag, drg, dRowsCount, Cols, cUB
    Erase Cols
    
    ' Return the concatenated destination lookup columns in an array.
    Dim dData() As Variant: ConcatJaggedColumns _
        dData, dJag, dRowsCount, cUB, ARE_BLANKS_A_MATCH, CONCAT_DELIMITER
    Erase dJag
    
    ' MATCH
    
    ' Return the source lookup matching row indices in an array.
    Dim srIndices() As Variant: srIndices = Application.Match(dData, sData, 0)
    drg.EntireRow.Columns("H").Value = sData
    drg.EntireRow.Columns("I").Value = dData
    drg.EntireRow.Columns("J").Value = srIndices
    Erase sData
    Erase dData
    
    ' RETURN
    
    ' Return the source return columns in an array.
    SplitStringToIntegers Cols, cUB, SRC_RETURN_COLUMNS, COLUMNS_DELIMITER
    
    ' Populate the source return array.
    JagColumnRanges sJag, srg, sRowsCount, Cols, cUB
    Erase Cols
    
    ' Return the destination return columns in an array.
    SplitStringToIntegers Cols, cUB, DST_RETURN_COLUMNS, COLUMNS_DELIMITER
    
    ' Define the destination return array.
    ReDim dJag(0 To cUB)

    ' Populate the destination return array with arrays.
    Dim drData() As Variant: ReDim drData(1 To dRowsCount, 1 To 1)
    Dim rc As Long
    For rc = 0 To cUB
        dJag(rc) = drData
    Next rc
    Erase drData
    
    ' Populate the destination return array with the matching values.
    JagMatches dJag, dRowsCount, srIndices, sJag, sRowsCount, cUB
    Erase sJag
    Erase srIndices
    
    ' Copy the values from each array in the destination return array
    ' to the correcponding return column range.
    For rc = 0 To cUB
        drg.Columns(Cols(rc)).Value = dJag(rc)
    Next rc
            
    ' Inform.
    MsgBox "Data matched.", vbInformation
    
End Sub

Help
Sub SplitStringToIntegers( _
        ByRef SplitArray As Variant, _
        ByRef SplitUB As Long, _
        ByVal StringToSplit As String, _
        Optional ByVal SplitDelimiter As String = ",")
    
    Dim StringArray() As String:
    StringArray = Split(StringToSplit, SplitDelimiter)
    SplitUB = UBound(StringArray)
    
    Dim VariantArray() As Variant: ReDim VariantArray(0 To SplitUB)
    
    Dim c As Long, sStr As String
    For c = 0 To SplitUB
        sStr = StringArray(c)
        If IsNumeric(sStr) Then
            VariantArray(c) = CLng(StringArray(c))
        Else
            VariantArray(c) = StringArray(c)
        End If
    Next c

    SplitArray = VariantArray

End Sub

Sub JagColumnRanges( _
        ByRef Jag() As Variant, _
        ByVal rg As Range, _
        ByVal RowsCount As Long, _
        ByVal Cols As Variant, _
        ByVal cUB As Long)
    ReDim Jag(0 To cUB)
    Dim c As Long
    For c = 0 To cUB
        Jag(c) = GetRange(rg.Columns(Cols(c)))
    Next c
End Sub

Function GetRange(ByVal rg As Range) As Variant
    If rg.Cells.CountLarge = 1 Then
        Dim Data() As Variant: ReDim Data(1 To 1, 1 To 1)
        Data(1, 1) = rg.Value
        GetRange = Data
    Else
        GetRange = rg.Value
    End If
End Function

Sub ConcatJaggedColumns( _
        ByRef Data() As Variant, _
        Jag() As Variant, _
        ByVal RowsCount As Long, _
        ByVal cUB As Long, _
        ByVal AreBlanksAMatch As Boolean, _
        Optional ByVal ConcatDelimiter As String = "\")

    ReDim Data(1 To RowsCount, 1 To 1)
    Dim dlen As Long: dlen = Len(ConcatDelimiter)
    
    Dim sStr As String, tStr As String, r As Long, c As Long
    Dim HasRowValue As Boolean, IsValid As Boolean
    
    For r = 1 To RowsCount
        tStr = vbNullString
        IsValid = True
        HasRowValue = False
        For c = 0 To cUB
            sStr = CStr(Jag(c)(r, 1))
            If AreBlanksAMatch Then
                If Not HasRowValue Then
                    If Len(sStr) > 0 Then HasRowValue = True
                End If
            Else
                If Len(sStr) = 0 Then
                    IsValid = False
                    Exit For
                End If
            End If
            tStr = tStr & sStr & ConcatDelimiter
        Next c
        If AreBlanksAMatch Then
            If IsValid Then
                If Not HasRowValue Then IsValid = False
            End If
        End If
        If IsValid Then
            Data(r, 1) = Left(tStr, Len(tStr) - dlen)
        End If
    Next r
            
End Sub

Sub JagMatches( _
        ByRef drJag() As Variant, _
        ByVal dRowsCount As Long, _
        srIndices() As Variant, _
        srJag() As Variant, _
        ByVal sRowsCount As Long, _
        ByVal cUB As Long)

    Dim sRow As Variant, dRow As Long, rc As Long

    For dRow = 1 To dRowsCount
        sRow = srIndices(dRow, 1)
        If IsNumeric(sRow) Then
            For rc = 0 To cUB
                drJag(rc)(dRow, 1) = srJag(rc)(sRow, 1)
            Next rc
        End If
    Next dRow

End Sub

A Byproduct: Arrays and the Split Function

Copy this to a new workbook and open the VBE.
Also, open the Immediate and the Locals windows.
Run the code and on each stop review the comments and what's happening in the windows and continue with F5.
You could also step through the code using F8.

Sub Test()
    Dim ErrCount As Long
    On Error GoTo ClearError ' start error-handling routine

    Const STRINGS As String = "A,B,C"
    Const DIGITS As String = "1,2,3"
    Const MIXED As String = "1,A,3"
    Const DELIMITER As String = ","
    Const MAX_ERRORS_ALLOWED As Long = 20
    
    Dim anInteger As Long, IsArrayAllocated As Boolean
    
    ' Basic
    
    Dim Arr() As String
    
    ' An attempt to retrieve the limits from an unallocated array produces
    ' 'Run-time error '9': Subscript out of range'.
    Debug.Print "[LB=" & LBound(Arr) & ", UB=" & UBound(Arr) & "]"
    
    Stop
    
    ' To check if an array is allocated you could use something like this:
    On Error Resume Next ' defer error trapping
        anInteger = LBound(Arr)
        IsArrayAllocated = (Err.Number = 0)
    On Error GoTo 0 ' enable error trapping
    Debug.Print "The array is " & IIf(IsArrayAllocated, "", "not") _
        & " allocated."
    
    On Error GoTo ClearError ' restart error-handling routine
    
    Stop
        
    ' Declaring the variable as a Variant without parentheses produces
    ' a Variant holding a Variant array ('Variant/Variant()').
    Dim ArrVarVar As Variant: ReDim ArrVarVar(0 To 1)
    ArrVarVar(0) = 1: ArrVarVar(1) = 2
    Debug.Print "ArrVarVar", VarType(ArrVarVar), TypeName(ArrVarVar)
        
    Stop
        
    ' Declaring the variable with parentheses produces
    ' an array of the specified type (e.g. 'Variant()' or 'Long()').
    
    Dim ArrVar() As Variant: ReDim ArrVar(0 To 1)
    ArrVar(0) = 1: ArrVar(1) = 2
    Debug.Print "ArrVar", VarType(ArrVar), TypeName(ArrVar)
        
    Dim ArrLng() As Long: ReDim ArrLng(0 To 1)
    ArrLng(0) = 1: ArrLng(1) = 2
    Debug.Print "ArrLng", VarType(ArrLng), TypeName(ArrLng)
        
    Stop
    
    ' Declaring the variable as a Variant without parentheses
    ' and assigning an array of a specified type to it produces
    ' a Variant holding this specifically typed array ('Variant/Long()').
    Dim ArrVarLng As Variant: ArrVarLng = ArrLng
    Debug.Print "ArrVarLng", VarType(ArrVarLng), TypeName(ArrVarLng)
    
    ' Note how the VarType and TypeName functions return the same
    ' for each array type.
    ' Open the Locals Window to see the difference.
    
    Stop
    
    ' The Split Function
        
    ' The result of the Split function is always a zero-based array
    ' even if Option Base is set to 1
    ' (the same goes for the Array function if '... = VBA.Array(...)' is used).
        
    ' Declaring the variable with as a Variant or any other type
    ' different than the String type produces
    ' 'Run-time error '13': Type mismatch': WRONG.
    Dim Arr13() As Variant: Arr13 = Split(STRINGS, DELIMITER)
    
    Stop
    
    ' Declaring it with 'Dim Arr As Variant' produces
    ' a Variant holding a String array: OK.
    Dim ArrV As Variant: ArrV = Split(STRINGS, DELIMITER)
    Debug.Print "ArrV", VarType(ArrV), TypeName(ArrV)
    
    Stop
    
    ' Declaring it with 'Dim Arr() As String' produces a String array. OK.
    Dim ArrS() As String: ArrS = Split(STRINGS, DELIMITER)
    Debug.Print "ArrS", VarType(ArrS), TypeName(ArrS)
    
    ' Again, the VarType and TypeName functions return the same.
    ' See the difference in the Locals Window.
    
    Stop
    
    ' Splitting an empty string results in an allocated array
    ' with the upper limit smaller than the lower limit.
    Arr = Split("", DELIMITER)
    ' Let's prove this.
    
    ' Result:  [LB=0, UB=-1]
    Debug.Print "[LB=" & LBound(Arr) & ", UB=" & UBound(Arr) & "]"

    Stop

    ' Let's now check again if the array is allocated. We know it is
    ' because the previous Debug.Print line didn't raise an error.
    On Error Resume Next ' defer error trapping
        anInteger = LBound(Arr)
        IsArrayAllocated = (Err.Number = 0)
    On Error GoTo 0 ' enable error trapping
    Debug.Print "The array is " & IIf(IsArrayAllocated, "", "not") _
        & " allocated."
    
    On Error GoTo ClearError ' restart error-handling routine

    Stop

    ' Now let's cut to the chase. I started this to see
    ' whether the digits from the split Strng array will be automatically
    ' converted to integers when copied to a Variant array.
    Arr = Split(DIGITS, DELIMITER)
    
    Dim ArrL As Variant: ReDim ArrL(0 To UBound(Arr))
    
    Dim i As Long
    
    For i = 0 To UBound(Arr)
        ArrL(i) = Arr(i)
        Debug.Print ArrL(i), VarType(ArrL(i)), TypeName(ArrL(i))
    Next i
    
    ' Answer: They won't. So we'll have to convert them to Longs.
    
    Stop
    
    For i = 0 To UBound(Arr)
        ArrL(i) = CLng(Arr(i))
        Debug.Print ArrL(i), VarType(ArrL(i)), TypeName(ArrL(i))
    Next i
    
    Stop
    
ProcExit:
    
    Exit Sub
ClearError: ' continue error-handling routine
    ErrCount = ErrCount + 1
    If ErrCount > MAX_ERRORS_ALLOWED Then
        MsgBox "Run-time error ]" & Err.Number & "[:" & vbLf & vbLf _
            & Err.Description, vbCritical
        Resume ProcExit
    Else
        MsgBox "Run-time error '" & Err.Number & "':" & vbLf & vbLf _
            & Err.Description, vbCritical
        Resume Next
    End If
End Sub

